# Error with date.timezone

Tags: php, simplepie

Recently I have been getting the following error on my feeds in Simplepie:

```
Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'GMT/0.0/no DST' instead in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx.xxx/www/php/simplepie.inc on line 3636`
```

Now this might be to do with the fact my domain has recently changed servers and/or at the same time I upgraded the blog software from which the RSS feeds are served from.

I'm not sure what I need to change to stop this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a timezone. For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

Answer (score 1):

Either set it up in you [php configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) (php.ini).

Or at [runtime](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) using:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Amsterdan');
```